# V93K Pattern Compiler

Tags: origen-sdk

Are there any V93K or STIL pattern compilers supported by an Origen wrapper?  I see an IG-XL pattern compiler but that is all I found [here](http://origen-sdk.org/testers/api/OrigenTesters/PatternCompilers.html).  Given that people are making V93K patterns with Origen, how is the pattern compilation handled?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, and the IGXL pattern compiler isn't as flexible as I would like it to be. I was going to look into this but then our IGXL pattern compiler for the J750 broke (licensing errors that after 4 months IT/Teradyne still hasn't resolved) so my motivation to add it has disapparated. If you wanted to add this feature I don't think you'd be stepping on anything.

Comment: thx @coreyeng.  so do you use the lib/tasks directory to create .rake files to handle the V93K pattern compilation?

Comment: We do not. @rlaj just embedded the compilation process within the only V93K app we currently have in our team. I believe we just carry around the standalone version of the executable and call it directly with Ruby's system commands.

Comment: Definitely we see the V93K final pattern compiler being integrated into OrigenTesters before too long. We wouldn't package the compiler, but each company/app would set a config or environment variable to state where it lived.
Then when you run `origen g my_pat` you would have an option to go straight to binl.gz. As @coreyeng mentions, within NXP we currently have a few custom implementations of that. We are just waiting to see who blinks first and takes the time to make one of them the standard approach :-)